# Posistion elements inside form

Tags: javascript, html, css

Heads up only been doing this for a couple days.

I have a form with one text field and one button. Trying to center the text field and button side by side inside of my form.

```css
.row {
  width: 100%;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
  display: flex; flex-wrap: wrap;
}
.col-6 {
  width: 50%;
}

.form {
  margin 0 auto;
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<div class='grid'> 
  <div class='row'>
    <div class='col-6'>
      <form class='form'>
        <input type ='text' name='userGuess' class='userGuess'/>
        <button type='button' name='submitBtn' value='Submit' class='submitBtn'>Submit</button>
      </form>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

I tried a lot of different things and nothing seems to work how I want it too.

**Note**: Not entire CSS code, just basic framework so I didn't paste all of it.

thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Add `justify-content: center;` to your `.row`. Then read this article. 
https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/

Comment: Here's a fiddle. The center of the `.row` is in between the two elements. That's as close as you'll get without add special margin or spacing. As far as I know... https://jsfiddle.net/m9ytsbkc/

Answer (score 0):

I added a Div to Contain the two.
Here is the updated CSS with class Container.

```
 .row {
  width: 100%;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
  display: flex; flex-wrap: wrap;
  }
  .col-6 { width: 50%; }

 .form {
  margin 0 auto;
  display: block;
  }
  .container{
  width:100%;
  padding:1%;
  }
```

Here is your updated HTML with the new Div in it.

```
    <div class='grid'> 
    <div class='row'>
    <div class='col-6'>
    <form class='form'>
    <div class="container">
    <input type ='text' name='userGuess' class='userGuess'/>
    <button type='button' name='submitBtn' value='Submit' class='submitBtn'>Submit</button>
    </div>
    </form>
    </div>
    </div>
    </div>
```